# Add additional text field to magento review

Tags: magento, review

I'm trying to add an additional text field to magento's product review. It looks like maybe this would need to live in the 'review_detail' table, but beyond creating the column in the db and adding the field to the template file, I'm not sure how to add this field so that it will be integrated into the review system. Can anyone get me started in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added 2 extra field in review form just go to the frontend\base\default\template\review/form.phtml add two field as other text field.

Now go to app\code\core\Mage\Review\Model\Mysql4\Review.php

```
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
$detail = array(
'title' => $object->getTitle(),
'detail' => $object->getDetail(),
'nickname' => $object->getNickname(),
'email' => $object->getEmail(), // New field 1
'fname' => $object->getFname(), // New field 2
);
```

Now add email,fname in the review_detail table in the database also go to app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Review\Edit\Form.php also add :

```
$fieldset->addField('fname', 'text', array( // New field 2
'label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('First Name'),
'required' => true,
'name' => 'fname'
));

$fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array( // New field 1
'label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Email'),
'required' => true,
'name' => 'email'
));
```

before to

```
$fieldset->addField('nickname', 'text', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname'),
'required' => true,
'name' => 'nickname'
));
```

I hope now you can add extra fields in review form.

Thanks

Comment: Never edit core Magento functions. Overwrite them instead by building your own module or by creacting an identical filepath in your local folder.

Comment: After doing this, even if I write a review I can't see it in product reviews.. why?

Comment: we have to add new fields in app\code\core\Mage\Review\Model\Resource\Review.php instead of app\code\core\Mage\Review\Model\Mysql4\Review.php

Comment: How do I acheive this in magento 2

Comment: I have added new field in DB, But How Do I save that field in DB

Answer (score 0):

For the "Unable to post the review" error, you need to add this 2 new fields in the function _cropReviewData in app\code\core\Mage\Review\controllers\ProductController.php

```
protected function _cropReviewData(array $reviewData)
{
    $croppedValues = array();
    $allowedKeys = array_fill_keys(array('detail', 'title', 'nickname', 'email', 'fname), true);

    foreach ($reviewData as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($allowedKeys[$key])) {
            $croppedValues[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $croppedValues;
}
```

I hope this will help.