# Magento Reviews: Calling back values from custom added fields

Tags: magento, review

I followed the link below and added additional text field to magento review.

[Add additional text field to magento review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941032/add-additional-text-field-to-magento-review)

I have tested that values for the custom fields can be successfully posted and stored in the database and appearing at backend as well. However I am having trouble calling back this value out to frontend.

I used the code below to call it back, but nothing is showing.

```
<span><?php echo $this->__('<h2>%s</h2>', $this->escapeHtml($_review->getFname())) ?></span>
```

What step was lacking or done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Review has no EAV model and if you want to add new fields - you need to upgrade your `rating` table to achieve that.

Could you show where do you store this value, if you tell that the value exists in database.

Comment: It is stored at mage_review_detail
And at the backend where you approve feedback, I can see custom fields and values submitted there.